# How can I use DoctorJS with Emacs?

Tags: javascript, emacs, ctags, jsctags, etags

Is there a way to use DoctorJS (apparently it used to be called jsctags) to generate a TAGS file for Emacs?

I've been looking around and it seems to always use the vi tags style, but I could be missing something very obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

doctorjs does not appear to output emacs style tags. It does not accept the -e option.

Probably it would not be that difficult to add emacs tag support, as both emacs and vim tag files are a very simple format.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this fork, which does support the -e option: https://github.com/berenddeboer/doctorjs

Answer (score 0):

It claims to be compatible with ctags, in which case it hopefully accepts the same `-e` command-line option that tells ctags to run in etags mode, to generate TAGS for Emacs.

`jsctags -h` should display the available options, according to the github readme file.