# Locate JavaScript source code in Emacs

Tags: javascript, emacs

I use Emacs to write web app in Rails + Angularjs.

Since angularjs api doc is not so great, I've to check angularjs source code frequently.

It's easy to locate ruby method code in irb console.

Is it possible to easily locate js source code from node console or emacs?

I also open to other editors and other solution. But no IDE, cause my computer is Ubuntu.

Edit: http://docs.angularjs.org/api has view_source feature. It can help me locate the source easily. But only for angularjs1.2.0rc1

Comment: are you looking for tags? (http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Tags.html) ?

Comment: @akonsu, not exactly, similar as tags, but I prefer solution focus on javascript, not a general solution

Comment: [Tern](http://ternjs.net) (by Marijn Haverbeke) works quite well for me.

Comment: `js2-mode` integrates with `imenu` - I'd try to investigate this approach. This might be better then tags because `js2-mode` has a better understanding of the source structure. But I didn't explore this possibility in detail.

Comment: @huaiyuan, I try Tern several month ago, but not installed successfully on my local. Maybe I need to review it again

Answer (score 3):

[Exuberant ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) supports javascript [among others](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/languages.html), and with the `-e` option (or when using `etags`) generates an Emacs-compatible TAGS file.

(There's also [jsctags](https://github.com/mozilla/doctorjs), but [last I heard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474864/how-can-i-use-doctorjs-with-emacs) this did not provide Emacs support.)

Once you have a compatible TAGS file, see the [Wiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CategoryNavigation) for usage details.

Take careful note that Emacs provides its own ctags & etags binaries, which are different to the ones provided by Exuberant ctags (in particular the former does not support javascript, but the latter is more comprehensive in general). Make sure that you're running the program you think you're running. (If you pass the `--version` flag, "Exuberant Ctags" will declare itself as such.)